# Set null on cascading delete

Tags: jpa, cascade

There are three tables, `t1, t2` and `t3`. t1 is referenced by `t2.fk2`, and t2 is referenced by `t3.fk3`. The first relationship is set `Cascading.ALL`, so removing one row of t1 will delete one related row of t2 at the same time. But how to set null of t3 on delete t2? (t2 can be directly removed, and cascaded removal from t1's delete).

This can be easily done in MySQL, but in JPA I really don't know what to do. I looked for answers, and `@PreRemove`, `orphanRemoval=true` can solve my problem?

Thanks a billion!!

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself. Get the t3s of the t2 you will remove, and set their t2 to null.

Comment: @JBNizet  Great thanks! Manually set fields is straightforward and works! The lesson here is when considering that JPA/Hibernate is an ORM mapper, things are clear and easier to solve.

Comment: Have you tried using defining a JPA 2.1 ForeignKey and setting "ON DELETE NULL" ?

Comment: @Neil Stockton I will try that, and manual setting and PreRemove can also work for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting fields to null works, e.g,  `t2.getT3XXField().setT2XXField(null)`.

You can also use `@PreRemove` callback in `t2` to do this.

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove(){

    T3Field.setT2Field(null);
}
```

Both ways work. Also, do not use `Cascade.ALL` or `REMOVE` on t2 for t3, because removing t2 will remove t3 entity, but in this scenario we don't want to set t3 null.